# How to stop fragments reloading/recreation in Jetpack navigation

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to use the new Jetpack navigation component. I use a BottomNavigationView with the navController : NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(bottomNavigation, navController)

But when I'm switching fragments, each fragment will be reloaded! is there any way to stop fragment reloading/refreshment?

Comment: Unfortunately, currently it is not possible. There are some approaches out there...

Comment: like what approaches can be implemented can you please tell me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had problems with reloading also. This helped me.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
...
val navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.mainFragment) 
bottomNavigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
                if (it.itemId != bottomNavigation.selectedItemId)
                    NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(it, navController)
                 true

}
```

This this stopped reloading on multiple clicks on bottom navigation item.

Comment: Thanks for the answer this works fine. In my fragment I have a scrollview and when i scroll and leave the fragment a and go to fragment b and when i again return to fragment a instead of loading from where i left it starts reloading again. I rummaged all the internet for an answer but i found none and some are in kotlin which makes hard to convert to java. So, can you please help me with a solution.

Comment: This answer only prevent to reload visible fragment.

Comment: setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener deprecated